# How to schedule an hourly check on a list a bulk 404 URL checker?

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a Google sheet that checks the response of a list of URLs (around 30) of them. I would like it to be scheduled every hour. It doesn't matter when in the hour the URL responses are checked but it would be preferable it's done every 60 minutes and also works when I'm not accessing the spreadsheet (i.e. offline)

I'm very new to using google sheets script editor so still trying to get to grips with it.
I used the script below. In the script editor I did the following:

- Edit > Project Triggers > Add Trigger.
- Choose Function > HTTP Response
- Even source > Time driven
- Select type of time based trigger > hour timer.

---

```
function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
 var response_code ;
try {
 response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
 }
catch( error ) {
 response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] 
;
 }
finally {
 return response_code ;
 }
}
```

I expected the above setup to update the URL checks every hour...but they only seem to update when I manually update the cell.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkUrls( ) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');//set ss id
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//set sheet name
  var urlA=['https:example.com','http://example.com'];//u pick em
  for(var i=0;i<urlA.length;i++) {
    var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "'yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss");//change format if you wish
    var response=UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlA[i]);
    sh.appendRow(ts,urlA[i],response.getResponseCode());
  }
}
```

Setting up the Timer:

```
function setupHourlyTimer() {
  if(!isTrigger('checkUrls')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkUrls').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}

function isTrigger(funcName){
  var r=false;
  if(funcName){
    var allTriggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for(var i=0;i<allTriggers.length;i++){
      if(funcName==allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction()){
        r=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply Cooper.

So I've placed the two scripts in the script editor and have a column in my worksheet  calling the GetStatusCode("URL"). 
To add the hourly triggers....do i set the event source to be from the spreadsheet or the timer?

Comment: I don’t understand your comment regarding the getStatusCode( URL).  As for your question, do whatever you think is best and if that doesn’t work try the other way

Comment: Hi Cooper. I've managed to get it working now with your script. Thanks very much.